# i am not able retrieve array elements one at a time if i call them in my component all the elements are retrieved at a time

Tags: reactjs

I want to load my array element when an event is occurred by referencing the key i tried different variables for the key but it would not accept all the elements of the array are being displayed if i give index as the key.
I am new to Reactjs and not very familiar with all the syntax and concept can somebody help me with the logic to solve this.

The event I am triggering is onClick or onChange.

```
`var Qstn =['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']; 

 <div>

  {Qstn.map(function(Q,index){
             return <span className="col-md-4 txt" key={index}>{Q}</span>

             })}
             </div>`
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to do... You want the
```<span className="col-md-4 txt" key={index}>{Q}</span>``` to appear  when the onClick is executed????

Comment: yes when the event is triggered the array elements from A to J should be displayed one at a time

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made a codepen with an example

http://codepen.io/lucaskatayama/pen/QGGwKR

It's using ES6 classes components, but it's easy to translate.

You need to set initial state to an empty array like [].
On click button, it call onClick() method which uses `this.setState({})` to change component state.

When React notice state changes, it re-render the component.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    //Initial State
    this.state = {
      Qstn : []
    }
  }

  onClick(){
    //Called on click button
    // Set state to whatever you want
    this.setState({Qstn : ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']})
  }
  render(){
    let Qstn = this.state.Qstn; // load state and render
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.onClick()}>Click</button> 
        <div>
            {Qstn.map(function(Q,index){
               return <span className="col-md-4 txt" key={index}>{Q}</span>

            })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}




ReactDOM.render(<Hello />,  document.getElementById('container'))
```

Comment: thank you for the help but what i want is when i click button the onClick must retreive only one array element starting form A can you help me with that

Comment: Just change how onClick works..Instead of setting the complete array... push element to it.
`var currArr = this.state.Qstn
currArr.push('A')
this.setState({Qstn : currArra})`